# Extract email id from field mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a column First_Name. But it has names along with email ids. eg. 'bobbybob@gmail.com Bobby' and sometimes like this, 'Bobby bobbybob@gmail.com'

I want to fetch email id from first_name column.

I tried this way:

```
select left(First_Name,locate(' ',First_Name)-1)
from mytable
where First_Name like '%gmail%' and Email_Personal=""
```

But this works in only first case where email id is first while in second case where name is first, it fetches name. I also want to remove email id after storing it into another column -Email_Personal. So, in other words, I want to fetch email id from first_name and want to store it into email_personal and keep only name in the first_name.

I've also tried this way:

```
select substring_index(first_name,' ',1) 
from mytable
where First_Name like '%gmail%' and Email_Personal1=""
```

But this also worked for the first case only. Where there is name first then, it returns only name not email id.

Comment: Always a 1 word name?

Comment: I found record where there is only one word name along with email id. So yes.

Comment: Also there is record like this, eg. 'bobbybob@gmail.com2012' no space in between also no name. Just want to remove that 2012 too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you always have a 1-word first name, you can do:

```
select (case when substring_index(first_name, ' ', 1) like '%@%'
             then substring_index(first_name, ' ', -1)
             else substring_index(first_name, ' ', 1)
         end) as RealFirstName
```

You can use similar logic to extract the email address:

```
select (case when substring_index(first_name, ' ', 1) like '%@%'
             then substring_index(first_name, ' ', 1)
             else substring_index(first_name, ' ', -1)
         end) as EmailAddress
```

Comment: Thanks. I get little bit confused with 1,1 and -1 in these 3 lines. Yes its worked that way. Then How can i remove it from first name?

Comment: Ok, I did it with replace in update query. Thanks a lot. But please clear my doubts for 1,1,-1 values in case part of select statement.

Comment: What if there are multiple words. I've another column Residence_Address in which also there are some email ids. Few values are separated by ',' (comma) also.

Comment: @iks_in . . . You should ask another question about `Residence_Address` with appropriate sample data and desired results.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively you could find the `@` and get all text until first space in both directions:

```
select 
concat (
  reverse(substring_index(substring(reverse(First_Name), -- Bit before @
    instr(reverse(First_Name),'@')+1),' ',1)),
  substring_index(substring(First_Name,                  -- Bit after @
    instr(First_Name,'@')),' ',1) 
)
from mytable
```